# charles proxy only showing portion of requests?

Tags: android, ios, proxy

So i wanted to see the endpoints of this android/ios app calles "Bigo Live".

Like always, i've set up charles and started trackig.

Funnily, it only shows part of the traffic. for example: If i use the apps search, i DO NOT see the search request, however, i see the users avatars being downloaded.

This seems not like some usual SSL-Pinning. There pops simply NO request up in charles (Not even a failed one!).

I'd appreciate it if anybody has any idea what kind of background magic is going on there.

Answer (score 1):

The app might not transfer all the data over HTTP(S), but could use TCP or UDP as well. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132970/udp-packets-from-iphone-could-not-be-captured-in-charles-web-proxy-tool) to capture the traffic with Charles or use Wireshark.